# Delete empty object after deleting properties with undefined value

Tags: javascript

I have an object :

```
{
   a: undefined,
   b: 'B',
   c: { d: undefined }
}
```

I want to remove all properties with undefined values and remove parent property if object is empty.

```
function removeEmpty (object) {
            Object.keys(object).forEach((key) => {
                if (object[key] && typeof object[key] === 'object') {
                     removeEmpty(object[key]);
                }
                else if (object[key] == null || !object[key].length) delete object[key]
            });

            return object;
        }
```

I understand that doesn't work because when object[key] is pointed on 'c' proterty, this one is not empty.

Comment: undefined is invalid in JSON, so a little trick is to stringify the object and the parse it back.  E.g..  `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))`

Comment: @Keith, Mr Swarovski is talking about objecst not jsons

Comment: @assembler  I know..  read my full response...

Comment: Just add `if (Object.keys(object[key]).length === 0) { delete object[key]; }` after you call `removeEmpty(object[key]);` ?

Comment: Thank you all. The  @FelixKling 's answer works fine !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just check whether you can remove the object after cleaning it (actually, this is exactly what Felix Kling proposed). This version also addresses the issue pointed out by Keith:

```
function removeEmpty(object) {
    Object.keys(object).forEach((key) => {
        if (object[key] && typeof object[key] === 'object') {
            removeEmpty(object[key]);
            if (Object.keys(object[key]).length === 0) // <---- Check whether there
                delete object[key];                      // <---- no objects in current one
        }
        else if (object[key] == null || (typeof object[key] === 'object' && object[key].length === 0)) {
            delete object[key];
        }
    });

    return object;
}
removeEmpty({
    a: undefined,
    b: 'B',
    c: { d: undefined },
    test: 1,
    test2: 0,
    test3: []
})

// Produces {b: "B", test: 1, test2: 0}
```

---

Previous version:

```
function removeEmpty(object) {
    Object.keys(object).forEach((key) => {
        if (object[key] && typeof object[key] === 'object') {
            removeEmpty(object[key]);
            if (Object.keys(object[key]).length === 0) // <---- Check whether there
                delete object[key];                    // <---- no objects in current one
        }
        else if (object[key] == null || !object[key].length) delete object[key]
    });

    return object;
}
```

---

[image]

Comment: `{ removeMe: undefined, test: 1 }` = `{}` is that what your expecting?

Comment: @Keith good point. I copied the OP's code to work of and addressed only a specific issue. I believe the updated code works better. Thanks for your attention to details!

Comment: with new version you are removing valid properties evaluated as `false`, like `false` itself, or also `0`..
with original versions (with `!object[key].length` condition) author was removing empty arrays (which are valid also).

Comment: @Andrea my answer was supposed to target OPs original question, not ensure the completeness & correctness of the code for all the possible inputs. I don't even have a set of unit tests that declare the API contract to start with

Comment: sure, i agree with you. and in fact it was not targeting `I want to remove all properties with undefined` request, since it removed not only `undefined` values, but also `false`-evaluated values. now it does.